# Most efficient usage of substring()

Tags: java, string, performance

Just curious to know which among the two snippets below is the most efficient?

```
String outStr = inputStr.substring(20);
```

(or)

```
String outStr = inputStr.substring(20, inputStr.length());
```

Does the first snippet internally invoke a inputStr.length() in case the second argument is not present?

Comment: You can lookup the implementation of these methods yourself: the source code of the standard Java classes can be found in `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory.

Comment: public String substring(int beginIndex) {
 return substring(beginIndex, count);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly - it invokes `substring(beginIndex, count)`, where `count` is an internal field holding the number of chars. `length()` also returns `count`, however, and so it's +1 method invocation. Virtually the same.

But prefer the one-argument version - it is cleaner to read.

Comment: I'd expect that `length()` simply returns the `count` as well.

Comment: @bdares - yes, that's also in the answer (updated a few seconds before your comment)

Comment: The JVM will most likely inline these method invocations, so that at runtime there is really no difference at all.

Comment: even if it doesn't, it's still almost the same. Don't microoptimize.

Comment: +1 for cleaner to read, this is the most important consideration.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to run each of those a gazillion times in a loop and measure how long they take.

If one is noticeably faster, go for that one.

If you find the difference is negligible, optimise for readability (the first one).

*Measure, don't guess!* That is the *number one* rule of optimisation.

Comment: My serious advice to you is *don't bother*.  There are many (many) reasons why your 'benchmark' is likely to measure the wrong thing. Running them 'a gaziliion times in a loop' is unlikely to fairly compare them, and so unless you can make a real comparison *in situ*, I wouldn't waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

The first code, calls `String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` internally.

Code:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex) {
    return substring(beginIndex, count);
    }
```

Where `count` is

> The count is the number of characters in the String.

Answer (score 0):

If you lookup the source code for class `java.lang.String`, which you can find in the file `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory, you'll find these implementations (this is from JDK 6 update 26):

```
public String substring(int beginIndex) {
    return substring(beginIndex, count);
}

public int length() {
    return count;
}
```

In other words, your first line of code does really do almost exactly the same as your second line of code, there will be no difference in efficiency that will be noticeable in any way.